# Compare columns for highest value, and count result in another cell

Tags: numbers

I am looking for a formula which will compare the higher of two numbers in adjacent columns, and count the result of where in e.g. column B the value higher is than column C.

It would be really amazing if there was a way to limit the result to where an X is in column A. So, looking for, the magic formula for: X in A, whilst counting the highest numbers of B, compared between B and C.

Answer (score 1):

1. Fill column D with the following formula:

   ```
   IF(AND(A1=X,B1>C1),TRUE)
   ```

   Replace X with the number you wish to check for. This formula checks each row, returning true if the row's A column contains X and if the number in B is larger than C.
2. Enter the following formula in the cell for the result:

   ```
   COUNTIF(D,TRUE)
   ```

   This counts how many rows returned true for the previous formula.

Comment: @TWho great!  Mark it as answered for the benefit of others.  Cheers!